# Cannot resolve package org.junit in my test class

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I have this problem in my java IDE:

After adding the library to the Test Libraries, package `org.junit` is still missing.

[image: screenshot showing added library]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding your JUnit Library to your **Test Libraries**, the `org.junit` package is available for the sources in your **Test Packages**

Either move your Test `MatrixTest` into your **Test Packages** (preferred)
*or* **add JUnit** to your **Libraries**

The idea of putting tests into Test packages is to not deliver them in the final product while still have them in the project. Your final product will not need JUnit to run - only your tests do.

Comment: Welcome. Just pick out the answer that solves your problem best and accept it please. Once you gain enough reputation, it'd be nice if you upvoted other helpful answers as well.

Comment: I have only 8 reputation. So I cant voteup other answers

Comment: I know. But you will get there. Just try to add a little more explanation into your questions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this library to the classpath too.

Comment: Where?? I added it to Test Libraries.

Comment: @VojtaMatras In the place where you can edit classpath of your project in your IDE. And, please, specify a name of your IDE in your question next time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MatrixTest` should be in the "Test Packages", not "Source Packages". I think the JUnit library defined as it is is only used for the test package.